# Crop Row Detection script

Tags: python, opencv, crop, hough-transform

I want to detect crop rows using aerial images(CRBD). I have done the necessary image processing like converting to grayscale, edge detection, skeletonization, Hough Transform(to identify and draw the lines), and I also set the accumulator angle to math.pi*4.0/180, which I varied time after time.

The algorithm works well at detection approximately 4 crop lines, I want to improve it so that it can detect variable number of  crop rows, and it should be able to highlight this crop rows

Here is a link to the sample code I modified [Here](https://github.com/petern3/crop_row_detection/blob/master/src/line_detect_2.py)

```
import os
import os.path
import time

import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

### Setup ###
image_data_path = os.path.abspath('../8470p/CRBD/Images')
gt_data_path = os.path.abspath('../8470p/GT data')
image_out_path = os.path.abspath('../8470p/algorithm_1')


use_camera = False  # whether or not to use the test images or camera
images_to_save = [2, 3, 4, 5] # which test images to save
timing = False      # whether to time the test images

curr_image = 0 # global counter

HOUGH_RHO = 2             # Distance resolution of the accumulator in pixels
HOUGH_ANGLE = math.pi*4.0/18 # Angle resolution of the accumulator in radians
HOUGH_THRESH_MAX = 80 # Accumulator threshold parameter. Only those lines are 
                    returned that get votes
HOUGH_THRESH_MIN = 10
HOUGH_THRESH_INCR = 1

NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 10  # how many crop rows to detect

THETA_SIM_THRESH = math.pi*(6.0/180)   # How similar two rows can be
RHO_SIM_THRESH = 8   # How similar two rows can be
ANGLE_THRESH = math.pi*(30.0/180) # How steep angles the crop rows can be in 
                    radians


def grayscale_transform(image_in):
'''Converts RGB to Grayscale and enhances green values'''
    b, g, r = cv2.split(image_in)
    return 2*g - r - b

def save_image(image_name, image_data):
'''Saves image if user requests before runtime'''
    if curr_image in images_to_save:
         image_name_new = os.path.join(image_out_path, " 
            {0}_{1}.jpg".format(image_name, 
         str(curr_image) ))

def skeletonize(image_in):
'''Inputs and grayscale image and outputs a binary skeleton image'''
     size = np.size(image_in)
     skel = np.zeros(image_in.shape, np.uint8)

     ret, image_edit = cv2.threshold(image_in, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | 
                cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
     element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS, (3,3))
     done = False

    while not done:
        eroded = cv2.erode(image_edit, element)
        temp = cv2.dilate(eroded, element)
        temp = cv2.subtract(image_edit, temp)
        skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel, temp)
        image_edit = eroded.copy()

        zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(image_edit)
        if zeros == size:
            done = True

     return skel


def tuple_list_round(tuple_list, ndigits_1=0, ndigits_2=0):
'''Rounds each value in a list of tuples to the number of digits
   specified
'''
    new_list = []
    for (value_1, value_2) in tuple_list:
         new_list.append( (round(value_1, ndigits_1), round(value_2, 
                 ndigits_2)) )

    return new_list

def crop_point_hough(crop_points):
'''Iterates though Hough thresholds until optimal value found for
   the desired number of crop rows. Also does filtering.
'''

    height = len(crop_points)
    width = len(crop_points[0])

    hough_thresh = HOUGH_THRESH_MAX
    rows_found = False

    while hough_thresh > HOUGH_THRESH_MIN and not rows_found:
        crop_line_data = cv2.HoughLines(crop_points, HOUGH_RHO, HOUGH_ANGLE, 
      hough_thresh)

        crop_lines = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
        crop_lines_hough = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

        if crop_line_data is not None:

          # get rid of duplicate lines. May become redundant if a similarity 
            threshold is done
            crop_line_data_1 = tuple_list_round(crop_line_data[:,0,:],-1, 4)
            crop_line_data_2 = []
            x_offsets = []

            crop_lines_hough = np.zeros((height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
            for (rho, theta) in crop_line_data_1:

                a = math.cos(theta)
                b = math.sin(theta)
                x0 = a*rho
                y0 = b*rho
                point1 = (int(round(x0+1000*(-b))), int(round(y0+1000*(a))))
                point2 = (int(round(x0-1000*(-b))), int(round(y0-1000*(a))))
                cv2.line(crop_lines_hough, point1, point2, (0, 0, 255), 2)


            for curr_index in range(len(crop_line_data_1)):
                 (rho, theta) = crop_line_data_1[curr_index]

                is_faulty = False
                if ((theta >= ANGLE_THRESH) and (theta <= math.pi- 
       ANGLE_THRESH)) or(theta <= 0.001):
                    is_faulty = True

                else:
                    for (other_rho, other_theta) in 
                            crop_line_data_1[curr_index+1:]:
                       if abs(theta - other_theta) < THETA_SIM_THRESH:
                           is_faulty = True
                       elif abs(rho - other_rho) < RHO_SIM_THRESH:
                           is_faulty = True

               if not is_faulty:
                   crop_line_data_2.append( (rho, theta) )



           for (rho, theta) in crop_line_data_2:

               a = math.cos(theta)
               b = math.sin(theta)
               c = math.tan(theta)
               x0 = a*rho
               y0 = b*rho
               point1 = (int(round(x0+1000*(-b))), int(round(y0+1000*(a))))
               point2 = (int(round(x0-1000*(-b))), int(round(y0-1000*(a))))
               cv2.line(crop_lines, point1, point2, (0, 0, 255), 2)
               #cv2.circle(crop_lines, (np.clip(int(round(a*rho+c* 
                #(0.5*height))),0 ,239), 0), 4, (255,0,0), -1)
            #cv2.circle(crop_lines, (np.clip(int(round(a*rho-c* 
             #(0.5*height))),0 ,239), height), 4, (255,0,0), -1)
            cv2.circle(crop_lines, (np.clip(int(round(rho/a)),0 ,239), 0), 5, 
                            (255,0,0), -1)
            #cv2.circle(img,(447,63), 63, (0,0,255), -1)
            x_offsets.append(np.clip(int(round(rho/a)),0 ,239))
            cv2.line(crop_lines, point1, point2, (0, 0, 255), 2)


        if len(crop_line_data_2) >= NUMBER_OF_ROWS:
            rows_found = True


     hough_thresh -= HOUGH_THRESH_INCR

 if rows_found == False:
     print(NUMBER_OF_ROWS, "rows_not_found")

x_offset = min (x_offsets)
width = max (x_offsets) - min (x_offsets)
return (crop_lines, crop_lines_hough, x_offset, width)






def crop_row_detect(image_in):
    '''Inputs an image and outputs the lines'''

    save_image('0_image_in', image_in)

    ### Grayscale Transform ###
    image_edit = grayscale_transform(image_in)
    save_image('1_image_gray', image_edit)

    ### Skeletonization ###
    skeleton = skeletonize(image_edit)
    save_image('2_image_skeleton', skeleton)

      ### Hough Transform ###    
    (crop_lines, crop_lines_hough, x_offset, width) = 
                              crop_point_hough(skeleton)

    save_image('3_image_hough',cv2.addWeighted(image_in, 1, 
                               crop_lines_hough, 1, 0.0))
    save_image('4_image_lines',cv2.addWeighted(image_in, 1,crop_lines,1,0.0))

    return (crop_lines , x_offset, width)


def main():

    if use_camera == False:

        diff_times = []

        for image_name in sorted(os.listdir(image_data_path)):
            global curr_image
            curr_image += 1

            start_time = time.time()

            image_path = os.path.join(image_data_path, image_name)
            image_in = cv2.imread(image_path)

            crop_lines = crop_row_detect(image_in)

            if timing == False:
                cv2.imshow(image_name, cv2.addWeighted(image_in, 1, 
                                       crop_lines, 1, 0.0))

                print('Press any key to continue...')
                cv2.waitKey()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()


            ### Timing ###
            else:
                diff_times.append(time.time() - start_time)
                mean = 0
                for diff_time in diff_times:
                    mean += diff_time

        ### Display Timing ###
        print('max time = {0}'.format(max(diff_times)))
        print('ave time = {0}'.format(1.0 * mean / len(diff_times)))

        cv2.waitKey()

    else:  # use camera. Hasn't been tested on a farm.
        capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        while cv2.waitKey(1) < 0:
            _, image_in = capture.read()
            (crop_lines, x_offset, width) = crop_row_detect(image_in)
            cv2.imshow("Webcam", cv2.addWeighted(image_in, 1, crop_lines, 1, 
    0.0))

        capture.release()

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


main()
```

**Input Image**

[![Input Image][1]][1]

**Output Image**

[![][4]][4]

**Expected Output**

[![Expected Output][5]][5]

I have tried thresholding  with cv2.inRange() to find green lines, but am still not getting the desired out.

Also the algorithms seems to be only draw the crop_line_data_2 as shown in the **Output Image**, it doesn't draw the crop_line_data_1

```
def threshold_green(image_in):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image_in, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    ## mask of green (36,25,25) ~ (86, 255,255)
    # mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (86, 255,255))
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, (36, 25, 25), (70, 255,255))

    ## slice the green
    imask = mask>0
    green = np.zeros_like(image_in, np.uint8)
    green[imask] = image_in[imask]

        return green
```

Comment: Please fix the posting of your input images or post to some free hosting service and put the URLs here

Comment: @fmw42 I  need at least 10 reputation to post images as stated by stackoverflow.                     Here is the link to the  images in my other post [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60606294/detecting-crop-rows-using-opencv)